# Regarding an element being self adjoint

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra. Let $x,y\in A$ be self adjoint elements in $A$, with $x$ being invertible. Can we say that the spectrum of $x^{-1}y$ is a subset of the real line? I know this is true if $x$ was also positive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The golden rule for conjectures in operator theory:

**Every ad-hoc conjecture is most likely false for $2 \times 2$-matrices.** :-)

So here's a $2 \times 2$-counterexample for the question:
Let $A = \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ and
$$
x = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\ 
  1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{and} \quad 
y = 
\begin{pmatrix}
  4 &  3 \\ 
  3 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$$.

Comment: Anyway, this question does not really seem to be research level - but I couldn't resist to advertise the "golden rule". :-) (So I marked the answer as community wiki.)